# JSON Parsing not working for edittext

Tags: android, json, web-services

I am trying to fetch data from JSON web api. The URL of api include the ID number.  The code is working if the URL has the ID number. What I want is to user to input the ID number in edittext and then it gets added to the main URL. If I do like `String URL = "http://103.8.127.248:1002/serv1/Service1.svc/getassignedstaff/" + EditTextValue;`  the progress loader revolves on app opening and then there is no result shown. Also (in the main code) the result (name, mobile and email of the ID) is shown in textview as combined. Can it be shown in 3 different edittext?

```js
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example_load_list.Load_List$PlaceholderFragment" >

   
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editText1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_below="@+id/tv"
       android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
       android:ems="10"
       android:hint="Enter Booking ID"
       android:inputType="phone" />
 
</RelativeLayout>
```

```html
public class Load_List extends Activity {

  ArrayList<String> AD_C_List;
 ProgressDialog P_Dialog_TR;
 ArrayAdapter<String> ARR;
 AutoCompleteTextView AV;
 TextView TV;
    EditText ed1;
  
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.fragment_load_list);
   
  TV  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
  //ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
  
  String URL = "http://103.8.127.248:1002/serv1/Service1.svc/getassignedstaff/51610002"; 

  
  loading_data(URL); 
  
  }
 
  private void loading_data(String url) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
  
  
  AD_C_List = new ArrayList<String>();  
   
  P_Dialog_TR = new ProgressDialog(Load_List.this);
  P_Dialog_TR.setMessage("Fetching Data...");
  P_Dialog_TR.setCancelable(true);
  P_Dialog_TR.show();
  
  RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
 
  AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    
  client.get(url, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() { 
    
   
   public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable e,
     JSONObject errorResponse) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super.onFailure(statusCode, e, errorResponse);
    //This will called on 4xx HTTP error
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    System.out.println("Status Code ::: "+ statusCode);
    System.out.println("Error Response ::: "+ errorResponse); 
   }
  
  
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(int statusCode,
    org.apache.http.Header[] headers, final JSONObject response) {

   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//   super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);

   System.out.println("Success Response ::: "+response);
    
  
   P_Dialog_TR.dismiss();
                try {
     
       
                  JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject("GetAssignedStaffResult");
        String e_name = jsonObject.getString("EMAIL");
        String m_name = jsonObject.getString("MOBILE");  
        String u_name = jsonObject.getString("UserName");  
                
        String final_txt = " Email: "+e_name+"\n Mobile :"+m_name+"\n Username :"+u_name;
                  
        System.out.println("JSON Object: "+jsonObject);
        
        Log.d("Email : ",jsonObject.getString("EMAIL"));
        Log.i("Mobile :",jsonObject.getString("MOBILE"));
        Log.i("Username :",jsonObject.getString("UserName"));
                 
        
        for (int i = 0; i < AD_C_List.size(); i++) { 
         
        String item = AD_C_List.get(i);
        Log.i("Array List",item);
        }
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), u_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        populate_TV(final_txt);
      
       
      } catch (JSONException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
               
                }           
      
   });
  
  }
  
  public void populate_TV(String C_List) {
  
    TV.setText(C_List);
 } 
 
}
```

Comment: show us how you retrieve value of the EditText. I'm sure the error is there

Comment: I tried, `String URL = "http://103.8.127.248:1002/serv1/Service1.svc/getassignedstaff/" + Ed1;`   (where Ed1 is the edittext object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your base URL should be like this:

```
String baseURL = "http://103.8.127.248:1002/serv1/Service1.svc/getassignedstaff/";
```

and when you retrieve the value entered by the user from the `editText`, check that it is not null before starting to read your JSON

```
if (ed1.getText().toString().matches("")) {
    // prompt the user to tell that the edittext is empty
} else {
    String url = baseURL + ed1.getText().toString();
    // ans start reading your JSON
}
```

Comment: @metalurgus, I tried your code, the main problem still is that the progress loader revolves on opening the app rather than giving chance to the user to enter value in edtitext and then add the total URL and then show the result in textview.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried, String URL =
>   "http://103.8.127.248:1002/serv1/Service1.svc/getassignedstaff/" +
>   Ed1; (where Ed1 is the edittext object)

that's not strange. Edittext instance does not represent a text inside it. It will give you the information about it's class and something like instance ID instead of the text inside it. That's all about the method toString().
To see what does it pass to the url now, just add something like

```
Toast.makeText(Load_List.this, URL, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

After the line

```
String URL = "http://103.8.127.248:1002/serv1/Service1.svc/getassignedstaff/" +Ed1;
```

So to make it work you need to use

```
String URL = "http://103.8.127.248:1002/serv1/Service1.svc/getassignedstaff/" +Ed1.getText().toString();
```